# How can I initialize multiple variables of different type in a C# for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

this is what i did but i'am not sure if this is right

```
int e = 1;
int m = 500;
for ( e = 1; m = 500; e < 4; m >= 300; e++; m-100;)
```

Comment: If you already have e and m declared you don't need to re-declare them in your loop. Also does the value of m actually change with your loop? You should have to use -= since m - 100 doesn't actually change the value of m unless it's part of m = m - 100;

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do *is* possible, but you have a few pieces wrong.

You can execute multiple statements in each "area" of the for-loop structure, but you need to separate them differently. A *valid* loop would look like this:

```
for ( e = 1, m = 500; e < 4 && m >= 300; e++, m -= 100)
{
}
```

Notice that in the first and third blocks, you use commas to separate the initialization and increment/decrement statements. The second block has to be a *single* conditional, so I used && to AND them together.

I also fixed your "m" decrement statement so that it actually modified m. The subtraction operator is non-destructive, so wouldn't actually modify anything n your original code.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the for is the initialization section.  (The part before the first `;`.  So to initialize `a`, `b`, `c`, you can do this:

```
char a;
int b;
string c;

for (a = 'z', b = 28, c = "aardvark"; etc.)
```

Currently you are trying to initialize `m` after the first `;`, which won't work.

Comment: @BradleyDotNet, you are right.  I just focused on the initialization part of the question.  You're answer also helps with the other parts of the for loop.